# Creating Menus in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I want create menu item in asp.net MVC just as like as home and about us.I tried adding following code in "Site.Master" page.

<%: Html.ActionLink("Patners","Patner","Home") %>

And I've created one view called "patner" by right clicking on "Home" folder in solution explorer and checking the check box of "create strongly-typed view" and view content is "Empty". But it's giving error. How can I add a menu?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a strongly typed view, the controller action rendering this view needs to pass a model:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Patner()
    {
        var model = new SomeModelTheViewIsStronglyTypedTo();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And in `~/Views/Home/Partner.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Some.SomeModelTheViewIsStronglyTypedTo>" 
%>
```